# Numerical approximation for integral

Tags: probability, integration, numerical-methods

I have been struggling in evaluating the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1-\Phi(y)}{[1-\Phi(y)]\left[y\phi(y)+[1-\Phi(y)]\right]-[\phi(y)]^2}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{Z_i>y}Z_i \mathrm{d}\Phi(y)$$

In which $\Phi(y)$ and $\phi(y)$ are cdf and pdf of standard normal distribution respectively. It seems impossible for me to find an analytic solution for this integral; thus, I am seeking for numerical approximation for it. Can someone please guide me any approach of numerical approximation that may be applicable for this integral?

Comment: Are $Z_i$ distinct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worth a try to split the integration domain at $y = Z_i$ points.
Let $\Phi_c(x) = 1 - \Phi(x)$. Then
$$
J = \int_{-\infty}^x 
\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{Z_i > y} Z_i\right)
\frac{\Phi_c(y)\phi(y) dy}{\Phi_c(y)[y \phi(y) + \Phi_c(y)] - \phi^2(y)}
$$
Assume that $Z_i$ are ordered, that is $Z_1 < Z_2 < \dots < Z_p < x < Z_{p+1} < \dots < Z_n$.
Also, let 
$$
\omega(y) = \frac{\Phi_c(y)\phi(y)}{\Phi_c(y)[y \phi(y) + \Phi_c(y)] - \phi^2(y)}
$$
Then
$$
J = \int_{-\infty}^x 
\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{Z_i > y} Z_i\right)\omega(y) dy = \\ =
\int_{-\infty}^{Z_1}
\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{Z_i > y} Z_i\right)\omega(y) dy +
\int_{Z_1}^{Z_2}
\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{Z_i > y} Z_i\right)\omega(y) dy
 + \dots +
\int_{Z_p}^{x}
\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{Z_i > y} Z_i\right)\omega(y) dy = \\ =
\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k \int_{-\infty}^{Z_1} \omega(y) dy + \sum_{k=2}^n Z_k \int_{Z_1}^{Z_2} \omega(y) dy + \sum_{k=3}^n Z_k \int_{Z_2}^{Z_3} \omega(y) dy + \dots
+ \sum_{k=p+1}^n Z_k \int_{Z_p}^x \omega(y) dy.
$$

Since $\int_{-\infty}^{-9} \omega(y) dy$ is approximately $10^{-19}$ one can change $-\infty$ to $-9$.
$$
J \approx \sum_{k=1}^n Z_k \int_{-9}^{Z_1} \omega(y) dy + \sum_{k=2}^n Z_k \int_{Z_1}^{Z_2} \omega(y) dy + \sum_{k=3}^n Z_k \int_{Z_2}^{Z_3} \omega(y) dy + \dots
+ \sum_{k=p+1}^n Z_k \int_{Z_p}^x \omega(y) dy
$$

The function $\omega(y)$ is quite smooth, so it should not be a problem to evaluate each of the integrals numerically with a Gaussian quadrature, for example.

Direct computation of $\omega(y)$ with $\Phi_c(y) = \frac{1}{2}(1-\operatorname{erf}(y/\sqrt{2}))$ function becomes numerically unstable for $y > 4$, so one should use the complement error function  $\Phi_c(y) = \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}(y/\sqrt{2})$. That allows evaluating $\omega(y)$ up to values $y \lesssim 100$, but for large $y$ one may use Laurent series of $\omega(y)$ and that is
$$
\omega(y) = y^3+7 y-\frac{10}{y}+\frac{118}{y^3}-\frac{1594}{y^5}+\frac{25366}{y^7} -\frac{458458}{y^9} + \frac{9196678}{y^{11}}+ O(y^{-13}).
$$

Comment: Thanks @uranix for the great solution. I just have one more question in using asymptotic expansion series: since the expansion is divergent asymptotic, will it be good enough to approximate the integral?

Comment: @Ocean the series is divergent in the following sense: taking any $y > 0$, the $[\omega(y)]_n \to \infty$ when $n \to \infty$. Here $[f]_n$ is truncation of the series at $n$-th term. But if you take some fixed $n$ then the series are good enough to approximate $\omega(y)$ for some range $[y_0, +\infty]$.